# Sphinx error in converting latex to pdf

Tags: errors, documentation, python

I'm trying to convert latex to pdf of CherryPy docs for offline usage. After I generated the latex I changed into build/latex directory and run "make all-pdf" and error happened. Sorry I don't know to fix this.
I attached the error log here http://errorpaste.appspot.com/logs/1001/sphinx-convert-latex-to-pdf-error

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Judging from the error message, the poster is running Debian - "(TeX Live 2009/Debian)" is in the error message.

Comment: actually I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. I've installed Sphinx via pip.

Answer (score 2):

The line `! LaTeX Error: File 'fancybox.sty' not found.` indicates that you are missing the [fancybox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancybox) LaTeX package. If you are using the Debian/Ubuntu TeXLive package this (and other missing packages) can be installed as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended
```

Comment: Note that there are further packages not found, not just the `fancybox` package.

Comment: further note that the document requests ec fonts, which are also missing...

Comment: @MartinScharrer that helps a bit but as you already mentioned it still lacks other package. I still get errors.

Comment: @ronbeltran: You could use `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` to install everything, if you don't mind the HD space.

Comment: WoW! texlive-full is 635MB and becomes 1194MB when unpacked! forget it I will now invoke "make html" but pdf is more tidy. anyway thanks